# Is asnyc : false really that bad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My question consists of two parts.

In my webpage, i am creating some of my divs dynamically using ajax post calls to get some information from db. Then i create my divs. My structure is as follows.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="createDivs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="useThatDivs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="useThatDivsMore.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, createDivs.js does the ajax call with async:false (because on later scripts, i use these divs)(and btw, it is a post call to the server), and gets the info from db, then create the divs according to the info.

So my questions are.

- **1) Does ajax calls should always be async? Then, my usage of ajax is
  completely useless/wrong here?**
- **2) If async:false is dreprecated, what should i use instead of this
  approach?**

Comment: There are always callbacks you can use to act after the data has returned. That's what you should be doing, not turning off async.

Comment: The way to do it is to make use of the callback mechanisms

Comment: Blocking UI is always bad. Your code could benefit from some restructuring, like executing contents of useThatDivs.js in the success callback of createDivs.js

Comment: Why not use callbacks like done, fail, etc.

Comment: @Andrew but if all my other scripts depends on this first createDiv.js, wouldnt it rip off the modularity? I mean scriptA does something with these divs, scriptB does something else. Putting everything to callbacks, is it really a good practice?

Comment: The fact that your other scripts rely on createDiv.js is what "rips off" your modularity. And yes; callbacks are a *much better* practice than turning off the "a" of Ajax.

Comment: Since javascript runs in a single thread using synchronous calls will block your interface, using callback is the efficient way for handling the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use callbacks of AJAX `success` and `error`. If you are using synchronous AJAX calls, than you are locking all interfaces of your website, till all responses are done.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '#',
    data: {id: 1},
    success: function(dataFromServer) {
       callFunctionToProcess(dataFromServer);
       /* OR */
       var directlyProcess = dataFromServer;
    },
    error function(data) {
       var yourRequestHasFailed = true; // e.g. you get 500 server error
    }
});
```

**EDIT FOR jfriend00**

It will not lock any other tabs of your browser, as it will not lock any of the following: OS, BIOS, house doors, car doors or any other lockable item.

Comment: "Locking all interfaces of your website" is not really what's going on.  The current user's browser (and only the current tab in some browsers) will be locked up until the synchronous ajax calls are done.  Yes, this is undesirable, but not really what you described.

Comment: @jfriend00 i don't say, that all browser will hang, only currently opened tab of website. And if there is delay between beginning and ending of responses (like 20s or more), than it's definitely not what you want and i think you will be losing clients too.

Comment: You said "you are locking all interfaces of your website".  If you meant only the open tab in your browser, then perhaps you should edit your question to say that instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a better solution i think you should look in to javascript promises. [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody prefers to use a UI that frequently goes unresponsive for 1-3 seconds.  They would much prefer to use a web-site that stays alive, even as they do things.  Really it's as simple as that.

It takes a little more work to design for async Ajax calls, but it generates a better user experience.  And, once you learn how and take advantage of tools available, it's not hard at all, just different than synchronous programming.

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery, you have jQuery's Ajax support available to you and every jQuery Ajax call returns a promise.  Promises can make async programming work more like (though not identical to) synchronous programming.  You can write something like:

```
$.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
    // process results here
});
```

If you want to sequence several asynchronous operations, you can even chain promises.

```
$.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
    // process results here
    // kick off next ajax call
    return $.ajax(...);
}).then(function(data) {
    // process results of 2nd ajax call        
});
```

Or, if you want to launch three parallel async operations (for better performance) and then do something when all three finish, you can do this:

```
$.when($.ajax(...), $.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)).then(function(data1, data2, data3) {
    // process results of all three ajax calls here
});
```

---

Oh, and if you want to use things like JSONP to do cross domain Ajax/JSON, you can ONLY use async.