# Is making java script execution synchronous better OR using setTimeout to fix something?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, synchronous

My drop-downs are populated with a lil delay seems like reading json takes time, to fix it I added setTimeout on setting the value on UI 
self.$(tab + " #viewBy").val(chartOptions.viewBy);
which works fine but want someone suggest making it synchronous is better way to do which doesnt not completely fix it as on load no options are loaded it loads only when another tab is clicked.

```
populateMenu = function (menuList, drpDownID) {                                                
     $(tab + " #" + drpDownID).html("");
     $.each(menuList, function (r, v) {
         console.log(tab + " #" + drpDownID+ " val : " + v.title); //this prints fine
         $(tab + " #" + drpDownID).append("<option value='" + v.id + "'>" + v.title + "</option>");
         console.log($(tab + " #" + drpDownID).html()); // this prints undefined for secondMenu
     });
   },

getSecondMenu = function () {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        async: false
                    });
                    $.getJSON("./js/abc/myJson.json", function (data) {
                        myJson= data;
                    });

                    for (i = 0; i < myJson.mod.length; i++) {
                        if (myJson.mod[i].id === tab.slice(1)) {
                            secondMenuList= [];
                            for (j = 0; j < myJson.mod[i].ett.length; j++) {
                                v = myJson.mod[i].ett[j];
                                secondMenuList.push(v);
                            }
                            populateMenu(secondMenuList, "viewBy");
                        }
                    }
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        async: true
                    });
                },

onloadCall = function () {
                    $(self.el).html(self.template());
                    self.$(tab).html(self.cntrlTemplate());  
                    self.$("#firstTab").ready(loadTab);
                    self.$("[id^=tabs-]").click(loadTab);
                    getfirstMenu(); //this drop down is loading fine it's from a ajax call
                    getSecondMenu(); //this comes blank first as I have made json reading sync
                },
```

Comment: Synchronous is not a chioce, avoid it as much as possible. The `setTimeout` has its own good, but not every case.

Comment: It sounds like you're asynchronously fetching your JSON and when you try to apply the value "chartOptions.viewBy", it's not populated yet (i.e., your asynchronous call hasn't returned yet). If you can edit/update your question with a code snippet that illustrates how you retrieve your JSON and where that is in relation to the setting of the UI value, I can give you a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better is keep your ajax calls asynchronous and then trigger the use of the results of those ajax calls using the completion function or completion notification of the ajax calls.  No synchronous ajax required.  No `setTimeout()` required.  No global storage required.  Clean.

When you are using a `setTimeout()`, you are just guessing when the ajax call is going to be done which isn't a good thing (you will either guess conservatively and be late or you will guess a short time and sometimes miss it on a slow connection) and you are probably storing the ajax results in some global variable (for use by your `setTimeout()` which also isn't necessary.

If you post your actual code, we could suggest a good approach much more specifically.

Your users really, really don't want you to use synchronous ajax.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133294/is-asnyc-false-really-that-bad/25133888#25133888) for more info on why your users will appreciate async ajax.

---

I'd suggest you change to this where you process the results of the `getJSON()` call in the success callback so there is no timing issue:

```
getSecondMenu = function() {
    $.getJSON("./js/abc/myJson.json", function(myJson) {
        for (i = 0; i < myJson.mod.length; i++) {
            if (myJson.mod[i].id === tab.slice(1)) {
                secondMenuList = [];
                for (j = 0; j < myJson.mod[i].ett.length; j++) {
                    v = myJson.mod[i].ett[j];
                    secondMenuList.push(v);
                }
                populateMenu(secondMenuList, "viewBy");
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it helps. Though its not a ajax call I am reading json with getJSON on UI itself which is taking some time it seems.

Comment: @user1724317 - `getJSON()` is an Ajax call underneath - same issue.  What library is `UI`?  We can't help you in a very detailed manner when you don't show us any of your code or tell us what libraries you're using.  It's like we're blindfolded and you're hiding most of the problem.

Comment: @user1724317 - there's no `setTimeout()` in that code.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear my thing works fine if I add setTimeout while assigning values to dropdowns on UI self.$(tab + " #viewBy").val(chartOptions.viewBy); OR if I make it sync as in code (but doesn't works fine completely onload). So, which approach is better.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 I had the same thing initially but with that I have to put a setTimeout() on  UI self.$(tab + " #viewBy").val(chartOptions.viewBy); otherwise dropdowns populate after couple of sec's. So I think its better to use setTimeout than making it synchronous, what do you say?

Comment: @user1724317 - where is the line of code `UI self.$(tab + " #viewBy").val(chartOptions.viewBy);` in your code?  I can't help you if you don't show the code you're asking about and how it is called/run relative to the other code.

Comment: That is inside the loadTab function, I found the fix, I should do the onLoad call in getJson callback by which I don't need to make it synchronus or use setTimeout!